# After installing ssl certificate serve same content on http and https

Tags: ssl-certificate, debian-squeeze

I just installed rapidssl certificate on apache2 debian squeeze. I put all files inside apache2/ssl folder, edited default-ssl inside apache2/sites-available. Certificate is installed but after visiting https://www.mysite.com browser gives me empty -It works page. How can I enable the same content on secured https? Thank you

Comment: Did you alter the other configuration directives of the default-ssl file to match your HTTP listener?

Comment: @ShaneMadden No, I just updated default-ssl file to reflect certificates path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make other updates/changes to the default-ssl file to get it to correctly serve your website in the same way that the HTTP listener does.

The place I'd start based on your description of the problem would be the `DocumentRoot` directive, though there are likely other changes that will need to be made.

If you provide your configuration files and the output of `apachectl -S`, we can provide specific guidance on how to get it set up properly.

Comment: Hi, finally I disabled default-ssl site and add directives inside my working site using same path as with non secure connection. Is this the correct way?

Comment: Do you mean that you added a new virtual host on port 443 to your existing site file?

Comment: Yes I added new virtual host on port 443

Comment: That should work just fine, then!  Is it functioning correctly?

Comment: Yes I think so. I am glad that you approoved it, Thank you.